Docker compose stack and single containers
I am in need of your guidance on this one.
I am trying to figure out why doesn't docker compose run run the npm container in the stack, but rather it pushes it outside? See the screenshot.

As I have a docker-compose.yml with all the services, npm service is there to install packages and run the vite dev server. And ofcourse, since I do not have a command nor an entrypoint stated in compose file nor in the dockerfile itself, the npm container exits as it should.
When I run docker compose run npm npm run dev the npm run container gets pushed up above the docker-base stack. Why is that?
Thank you for shedding some light.

It looks like you're encountering a common scenario when working with Docker Compose, especially when using the docker compose run command to execute one-time commands for services defined in your docker-compose.yml.
When you use docker compose run to start a service, Docker Compose creates a new container for that command, separate from the containers it manages automatically for docker-compose up. To the best of my understanding, this behavior is by design, allowing you to run one-off commands or tasks for development, debugging, or administration without interfering with your currently running services.
The docker compose run command isolates the service you are running from services started with docker-compose up. It essentially treats the run command as an ad hoc instance, which is why you see it listed separately.
When running a service with docker compose run, it does not necessarily respect dependencies defined in docker-compose.yml unless explicitly told to do so with the --no-deps flag. It also creates a new container each time, which is why you see multiple entries if you run the command multiple times.
Regarding the npm service container exiting, since there’s no long-running process defined by a command or entrypoint (as you mentioned), the container will exit immediately after performing its task. This is normal behavior if the container's main process (in this case, running npm commands) completes.
If you want the npm service to stay up and be part of the main stack, you might need to consider defining a long-running process for it in your docker-compose.yml. Something like:
npm:
  image: node:latest
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  working_dir: /app
  command: npm run dev

If you just need to run commands occasionally and don’t mind them being separate, your current approach is fine. However, I have previously used docker-compose exec to run commands in an already running container (started by docker-compose up), which can sometimes be more convenient and keeps everything within the same stack.
This is an example of using exec to run a command in an already-running npm service:
docker-compose exec npm npm run dev

Make sure your npm service is configured to stay up without a terminating command for exec to work, such as using a dummy command like tail -f /dev/null to keep the container running indefinitely.
I hope this helps explain the situation, but if you have further questions, feel free to ask.

Thank you so much for taking your time. And yes, I was aware of the tail -f /dev/null trick. Was not sure if it is something I want/need. But as you explained and your personal experience is to use the exec command, I am more than glad to also use it. The trick here is also to use --service-ports for when you actually want that "new" container to listen and act like a part of the stack. Thank you again.

You are most welcome! Ah yes, the  service ports flag makes sense. Glad you found my view helpful.
